# Geography type in PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a PostGIS table but one column appears to have binary data.

```
CREATE TABLE test_geog2 (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    boundary GEOGRAPHY(Polygon)
);

INSERT INTO test_geog2(boundary) VALUES (ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((0 0, 0 5, 5 5, 5 0, 0 0))'));
```

Results after select query:

```
id                boundary
1                 0103000020E6100000010000000000000000000000000
```

The boundary appears to be very wrong character - what is wrong?

Comment: Why do you think that's wrong?

Comment: This is entirely normal, and how PostGIS's fields are represented internally. If you want a human readable format you need to use PostGIS functions to format it.

Comment: Andrew I thought it is wrong because it is not readable

Comment: Craig thanxs let me try to check the functions to convert to a human readable form.

Comment: I got the answer thanxs SELECT ST_AsText(boundary) 
       FROM test_geog2.  this gives in a human readable form